# Confidence level in bayesian network edges

Tags: python, python-3.x, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I have implemented(more correctly I have used bnlearn structure learning) a way to get a Bayesian network from my data.

`model_exact = bnlearn.structure_learning.fit(df)`

but I cannot get the confidence levels for the edges,(at least not in the model the package returned) is there some other library or way in bnlearn to get the confidence level for the edges? I have tried to look at the documentation but didn't found anything that seems to link to the confidence level.

or does anyone knows a way to control the number of edges when creating a Bayesian network in python? (that would help too)